# Matplotlib and datetime error date2num function AttributeError

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a graph with a list of datetime objects as one axis. I searched online and it seems I should call the date2num function. However, when I call it I get an Attribute error.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
listOfDates
[datetime.date(2013, 8, 20), datetime.date(2013, 8, 21)]
dates = mathplotlib.dates.date2num(listOfDates)
```

Here's the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#30>", line 1, in <module>
  dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(listOfDates)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dates'
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import the `matplotlib.dates` module explicitly:

```
import matplotlib.dates
```

before it is available.

Alternatively, import the function into your local namespace:

```
from matplotlib.dates import date2num

dates = date2num(listOfDates)
```

Comment: Oh, thay you very much! I thought when I imported the package it would import the whole thing

Comment: @AugustoDiasNoronha: Nested packages need to be imported explicitly. Sometimes a parent package does this for you, but not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

this error usually comes up when the date and time of your system is not correct. just correct and restart the whole console and it should work perfect.